# $\frac{2}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx \int_{ax}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz$

Tags: integration

If $a=\frac{1-\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$, how do I solve that integral?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The integration is over $0\le ax\le z\le\infty$, i.e. $0\le z\le\infty,\,0\le x\le z/a$. If we convert to polar coordinates in the obvious way, we get$$\tfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty re^{-r^2/2}dr\int_0^{\arctan(1/a)}d\theta=\tfrac{1}{\pi}\arctan\sqrt{\tfrac{1+\rho}{1-\rho}}.$$

Comment: Why did you pass to polar coordinates? Anyway the correct result is $\frac{\pi}{2}-\operatorname{arctg}(a)$.

Comment: @FrancesxoTotti Because it works. Your claimed answer is off by a factor of $\pi$ (try $a\to0^+$). Mine is right because for $a>0$, $\arctan a+\arctan(1/a)=\pi/2$.